# Unable to dynamically change class based on ViewBag value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here is my controller code where I have set the value of `ViewBag.Val` as 1. Now based on this value i'm trying to change the class of an href in my `Index` view but its not setting the class to `Class="A"`.

`<a @ViewBag.Val==1? class="A":class="B" href="#">
   Hello
</a>`

 I'm quite new to asp.net MVC, so any help would be appreciated.

But what i get is as shown below:

```
<a 1="=1?" class="A" :class="B" href="#">
    Hello
</a>
```

Comment: "not working as expected" is insufficient. Describe what happens, and what doesn't.

Comment: @HenkHolterman updated what i'm getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
@ViewBag.Val==1? class="A":class="B"
```

To

```
class="@(ViewBag.Val==1? "A": "B")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your razor code is wrong. Look at here:

```
<a class=@ViewBag.Val==1? "A":"B" href="#">
   Hello
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the ? conditional operator in your controller to determine the class you want in your View.

In controller:

```
int someInt = 1;
ViewBag.Class = someInt == 1 ? "A" : "B";
```

In view:

```
<a class="@ViewBag.Class">
```

Seems to be better SoC this way since you aren't bogging your View down with conditional logic.

Comment: But the class-names belong to the View. You're a little bit right about the logic but your solution breaks other rules.